# Swapping a business 'page' from one account to another.

Tags: facebook, swap, accounts

A photography partner of mine created two business 'pages' on his Facebook page. One for himself and one for me. I want to swap the business page that was made for me over to my personal facebook page. How do I do this? I want to keep the name of the page because it represents the business. facebook.com/my business name. Help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is for him to assign you admin rights to the page. Then you remove his admin rights.